# algorithm2e problem

Tags: algorithm2e

### Source code

I'm working on a [LaTeX project](http://www.inf.ufpr.br/~cjp07/tg.zip) which brings 5 files:

- `cassio.bib`: bibliography
- `comandos.tex`: a rich set of commands for easiness of typing
- `tg.tex`: document's source code
- `tg.pdf`: generated PDF
- `Makefile`: compilation tool

To compile it, type `make tg.pdf` to generate `tg.pdf`.

### The problem

I have a problem related to `algorithm` environment in `algorithm2e` package.

Within `tg.pdf`, plase take a look at page *33*. This algorithm should be placed within section (**5.2**) (in the page *32*) and right before section (**5.3**).
The corresponding code happens at line *1976* in the `tg.tex` file.

### A similar problem

A similar problem happens at `tg.pdf` (page 43).
This algorithm and the subsequent text (Parte I: Apêndice) should be separated by a page break; i.e., they should *not* appear in the same page.

My goal is to force `algorithm` to be rendered in the order it is written in `tg.tex`.
Could anyone help me figuring out where is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: This is the case when you work with floats since they are allowed to move around in a document. If you wish to avoid this (even at certain places), the [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float) offers an `[H]` float specifier that inhibits floating. In fact, see the FAQs [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/Qzz31) and [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://goo.gl/290dD) for more precise details.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for. You're very good!